# Decoupling custom user data

Tags: c++, design-patterns, shader, decoupling

I have a custom shader generation:

```
class My_UniformInt { public:
    std::string idName;
    int glsl_id;  //<-- userData-like field
};
class My_Shader{ public:
    My_UniformInt textureCoordinate;
    public: My_Shader(){
        textureCoordinate.idName="textureCoordinate";
    }
};
void registerUniform( My_Shader& shader, My_UniformInt & uniInt){
    uniInt.glsl_id=5; 
    //vec3.glsl_id=glGetUniformLocation(uniInt.idName);
}
void passUniformInt( My_Shader& shader, My_UniformInt & uniInt,int k){
    std::cout<<"successfully pass name="<<uniInt.idName<<" va="<<k<<std::endl;
    //glUniform1i(uniInt.glsl_id,k);
}
```

I can generate shader and use it like:

```
int main(){
    My_Shader shader;
    registerUniform( shader , shader.textureCoordinate ) ;
    //.. several frame later
    passUniformInt( shader , shader.textureCoordinate ,  5 ) ;
    return 0;
}
```

It works and fast ([MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd0759e744857407)), but there is undesirable coupling.
1. `My_UniformInt` caches glsl-specific variable (`glsl_id`).
2. `My_UniformInt` is also emotionally attached to the `glGetUniformLocation`.

How to make `My_UniformInt` more independent without sacrificing speed?

I have several cases that has similar issues.  Unfortunately, the most obvious choice usually seems to be adding more userData-like fields.  It increases coupling.

**My poor solutions:**

1. Make `glsl_id` as `void* userData`, then assign `userData=new int()`
   It is uncool + has a little cost + need to be deleted later.
2. Create a map `std::map<My_UniformInt*,int glsl_id>`.  I can't afford the cost though.

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean with "coupling". What are you trying to achieve? Why does a string need to be in the class?. But performancewise, if you know the possible values the string is going to have, I think it would be better to create the corresponding strings beforehand and then use those to fill your class My_UniformInt (which could also be a struct imo). That way you could use faster operations.

Comment: @tagelicht  The coupling is between glsl and `My_UniformInt`.  If I may change my render style to [AZDO](https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2014-gdc/Khronos-OpenGL-Efficiency-GDC-Mar14.pdf) , or support directX, or many styles later, I will have to add/remove field of `My_UniformInt`.  I am trying to eliminate that maintainability issue.  Yes, string doesn't need to be in the class.  I think it is deserved though, because in term of definition here, every instance of  `My_UniformInt` should has unique manual ID.  ... Why your approach is faster?

Comment: As to why my approach would be fast, the constructor of std::string takes way longer than just assigning a pointer to a string that is already initialized. Or, you could use an enum, depending on what you need it for. Also, structs are the preferred datatype for something that just holds some variables, because they have less overhead than classes, I think.

Comment: AS to the coupling, I think you should try wrapping code that uses the API in its own space so that it is easily exchangeable later - create a class that does the API access for you, and if you want to switch the backend, just adapt that class. Build the rest of your code in a way that it does not use any API-Specific code or variables, but instead uses your wrapper to interact with it.

Comment: @tagelicht As about performance of std::string, I am OK with it because it is done just once.   As to coupling, what you mention looks like a correct answer - perhaps with some more detail and pattern-name, you may post it as a solution.

Comment: @tagelicht I partially implemented it.  It looks very promising.  If you post your comment as an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Comment as an answer:

I think you should try wrapping code that uses the API in its own space so that it is easily exchangeable later - create a class that does the API access for you, and if you want to switch the backend, just adapt that class. Build the rest of your code in a way that it does not use any API-Specific code or variables, but instead uses your wrapper to interact with it.

I think this generally is a good way to deal with any kind of libraries or anything. It allows you to quickly adapt to changes within those by not relying on any kind of interface they provide, but only on your own interface. The challenge is to write the wrapper in a way that it provides good abstraction, so you can ideally use another backend that uses a completely different interface, yet trying to be as native as possible to ensure low overhead.